# Combining words from two lists

Tags: powershell, random

I'm experimenting and having a look at creating a randomizer from two lists.

```
$List = ’Red’,’Pink’,’Green’
$List1 = ’Warning’,’Election’,’Marriage’
```

What I'm looking to do is pick a random word from `$List` and `$List1`. I'm aware that you can pick from a singular with :

`Get-Random -InputObject $List`

However, I'm not quite sure how I would be able to grab from both lists and combine them.

My expected output would be:

> RedMarriage
>
> PinkWarning
>
> GreenElection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just continue your current logic and perform two `Get-Random` commands? Then you can just use your favorite way to combine two strings.

```
"{0}{1}" -f (Get-Random -InputObject $List),(Get-Random -InputObject $List1)
```

If you are looking for a concise, single `Get-Random` command to do the job, I think you will need to add more complexity to the code.

Comment: I think this may be the best solution going forward, the goal was to keep things minimal, however, if this results in more elsewhere there's little point. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$list1 = @( 'Red','Pink','Green' )
$list2 = @('Warning','Election','Marriage')

$idx1 = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $list1.Count
$idx2 = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $list2.Count

$result = "$($list1[$idx1])$($list2[$idx2])"

$result
```